# i'd like to make aquery that select rows from mysql database but the rows have data in arabic?

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I have a mysql table with Arabic data. The data looked like

```
Ø´Ù‚Ø© ØªÙ…Ù„ÙŠÙƒ Ø¨Ù…ÙˆÙ‚Ø¹ Ù…ØªÙ…ÙŠØ²
```

in the database.

When I make a query as:

```
select * 
from table 
where tit = "arabic letters"
```

It's give me the following error:

> Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL
>   result resource in
>   D:\LocalHost\Websites\Megadiv_Clients\immes_Realestate\website\admin\tours.php
>   on line 1437

Comment: Read [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/a/279279/623041).

Answer (score 0):

Mysql_num_rows requires a mysql resource (i.e. a query result).

Are you passing it a resource, or just a string?

It should be: `mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT ... "));`

Note: use of the [mysql extension is discouraged](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php), in favor of mysqli.

Comment: mysql_num_rows is not my problem, my problem is that i want to write the following query
$x=mysql_query("select * from table where title='كلام نموذج'");
$y=mysql_num_rows($x);

Comment: Hmmm, are you able to run that query in phpmyadmin or something? It could be a charset issue between your webserver/files and db causing issues making the query not get executed correctly maybe?

Comment: Hmm, then would it be something perhaps in php.ini to do with the charset? Is your charset correct? PhpMyAdmin may have a different charset, enabling you to do the search (i.e. where your site might scramble the arabic). Would you need UTF8 or unicode? or is unicode utf8? I'm not sure on the specifics! You can check your default_charset value in php.ini or `<?php echo ini_get('default_charset'); ?>` i think

Answer (score 0):

If `mysql_query` fails for some reason it returns `FALSE` instead of a resultset, and you can't use num_rows. You can call `mysql_error()` to find out what the error was. For example:

```
$x=mysql_query("select * from table where title='كلام نموذج'");
if (!$x) {
    die("Error from MySQL: ".mysql_error());
}
$y=mysql_num_rows($x);
```